# Long term access token for fan page. manage_pages permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I want to create a long term page access token. I have followed these steps.

**Find your user Token(2 Hours)**
developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

**Generate long term Token (2 months)**
    graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN is what you get from Find your user Token above.

**Page Access Token**

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts
Plug in long term access  token
 Enter https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts in the second text box
 Click on submit
 Json data will be returned
 From that select the access token of your Fan page

My problem is that when I enter in the long term access token  the Graph API Explorer I only get back the name , category and id. And not the access token. Which leads me to believe the long access token does not have the manage_pages permission but when I go to set it. I get back a short term token with the permission set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're not using the wrong token or the wrong permissions on the request to /me/accounts?

Check with a call to `/app` (to see if it's the correct app) and `/me/permissions` to check it's the right permissions, provided you have the the `manage_pages` permission and it's the long-expiry token (which you can check in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)) it should be OK

Comment: The Long term User access token does not have any permissions available. When I run /me/Permssions I get
`{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1, 
      "bookmarked": 1
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Then you're mixing up your apps or something, exchanging the token doesn't interfere with which permissions were granted

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer. The access code I was using was actually is assigned to Graph API Explorer. I think my question then is, how do I get the access code for a specific app with the `manage_pages` permission associated with it?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was taking the access token from the graph API and not the app I was working on so when I generated the page key it was associated with the standard 1or 2 hour key with no permissions.

I the the end I ran this code ``"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id ."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=". $scope ."&state=".$_SESSION['state'];``

to set the  permission and got back the the new correct access_token and ran through the rest of the steps like normal. 

Thanks guys.